# Are relative paths in a RequireJS AMD define() module relative to baseUrl?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

For example, if I have

```
define(['./path/to/Foo'], function(Foo) {})
```

Is `./path/to/Foo` resolved relative to the require.config's `baseUrl`, or relative to the that module's location?

Comment: Neither.  You would not want to provide any value here.  It should look like this:
define(function(Foo){}); then you would require using a relative path.  If you wanted baseUrl to come into play then you would NOT use a relative path.  The non-relative path would be relative to the baseUrl.  For example, require(["Foo"]) would work if baseUrl was "path/to".

Comment: I think you might have meant this:
define(["./path/to/Foo"], function(Foo) {}).  That is different than w/o the brackets.  In this case baseUrl doesn't matter.  define(["path/to/Foo"], function (Foo) {}) would be relative to the baseUrl.

Comment: Yep, I did mean to put brackets. So in my updated example, is `./path/to/Foo` relative to baseUrl, or relative to the file that has the dependency?

Comment: @CoreyAlix nvm, you answered in my answer. Thanks! If you want to put your answer, I'll accept yours instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes-relative-names, seems that it is resolved relative to the file regardless of baseUrl.

Comment: Only true if you add the square brackets.

Comment: @CoreyAlix Oh okay, I meant to have those. Thanks!